# Kohana 3 ORM. How to set up Inflector irregular word arrays in the Bootstrap or Model

Tags: orm, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3 ORM and it seems that the Inflector is singularising the word 'causes' to the form 'caus' instead of 'cause'. I have a _has_many_"through" relationship setup and even through all my foreign keys are setup to read 'cause_id' it still wants to setup an ON clause in SQL where it references 'caus_id' rather than 'cause_id'.

Is there a way to set up the Cause model to recognise the default singular form is 'cause'?

Or is there a way to add an Inflector->irregular array in the Bootstrap.php file?

I've hacked the SYSPATH.'config/inflector.php' file adding the exception and it does fix the problem but I would prefer a method that doesn't involve hacking the system files.

What is the 'best practice' approach please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy `SYSPATH/config/inflector.php` to `APPPATH/config/inflector.php` and change what you want. This will allow you to upgrade framework core without loosing your modifications.
2. Post an [issue](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana3/issues) and this will be fixed in the next release.